# MySQL: remove a user's permission to delete specific tables

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

**That is the question...** I have 30 tables in a database, and I want to avoid deleting information in five tables.

With this I will also understand how to avoid inserting in three tables. Of course, I have created a new user and still don't have any privilege.

Can this mechanic be done?

Comment: you can  try LOCK/UNLOCK TABLES

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [REVOKE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/revoke.html):

```
REVOKE DELETE ON contacts FROM 'user1'@'localhost';
```

Which would remove the DELETE permission on table `contacts`.

With mydb.*, for example, you can remove all DELETE permissions on all tables in the database `mydb`.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer, for me placing `dbname.tablename` worked, what I had to do was grant permissions and then remove the ones I didn't want them to have